# Apple Silicon M1 Mac compatibility for MacTeX, and performance

Tags: mac, mactex, performance, cross-platform

Has anyone had the chance to test the compatibility of MacTeX on the new M1 Macs (Mac Mini, Macbook Air and Macbook Pro)? What is the performance like?

Comment: The current MacTeX is a universal binary and will run on both ARM and Intel Macs. Performance itself seems opinion based and not really on topic.

Comment: I don't see how performance is opinion based. It can be measured and quantified.

Comment: My recollection (it's been a while since I read about it) is that out of the box MacTex is not universal binaries and that Mac's Rosetta is invoked to run the Intel binaries. But I believe the universal binaries are available and there are instructions to install them. (With some execeptions. I believe Asymptote was one of the exceptions.) See here https://www.tug.org/mactex/aboutarm.html

Comment: @JosephRedfern Benchmarking is objective in a sense, but depends a lot on the tests done, which is much more subjective. See [Tips for choosing hardware for best LaTeX compile performance](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/103565) for some general performance issues relating to TeX. The new chips do seem to be fast https://www.pcmag.com/news/early-benchmarks-show-apples-arm-based-macs-reign-supreme so there might be some speedup. But I really don't know how useful this is as a question for the site. (Nobody has voted to close, however.)

Comment: @dedded Thanks for clarifying that. The universal binary does require a separate update.

Comment: @AlanMunn So if I install mactex universal package on M1 Mac, and run “>>lualatex” from terminal, will the entire compile just use ARM binaries? Or is it that for some part of compile it would run ARM & another part it would use x86_64 (for library binary that’s not available as ARM)? I am glad this question wasn’t closed, performance is objective (if one controls the environment enough). Also MacTeX website suggests they used code base older than TeXlive 2020, does that mean M1 lualatex won’t support HarfBuzz. Can packages be updated to make that work?

Comment: @reportaman Your question is frankly much more interesting, since it's quite specific. Unfortunately  I don't have an answer for you. My understanding is that the universal binaries use all ARM code, though. If you want an answer you might be better of asking on the TeX on OSX mailing list (which is inhabited by the MacTeX developers.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not as simple an answer, and I'll divide my answer in two parts...

**Part-1: "Benchmark"**

Upon researching internet for a latex benchmark and a site that maintains/publishes benchmark results, I found  one: [benchmark](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/anton/latex-bench/), and its corresponding [results](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/franz/latex-bench) page. The steps are mentioned on the benchmark page. I repeated the same steps on Apple's new ARM based M1 Mac mini and my old Intel based MacBook Pro (relevant specs below), with all the following engines: latex, pdflatex, xelatex, and lualatex.

2020 Apple Silicon M1 Mac mini specs and results (using ARM binaries):

```
Mac mini M1, 2020
Chip Apple M1
Memory 16GB
macOS Big Sur 11.0.1

latex bench.tex  0.35s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.364 total
pdflatex bench.tex  0.53s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 0.549 total
xelatex bench.tex  0.72s user 0.04s system 107% cpu 0.714 total
lualatex bench.tex  1.24s user 0.03s system 99% cpu 1.279 total
```

2014 Intel based MacBook Pro specs and results:

```
MacbookPro Retina 13in, Mid 2014
Processor 2.6GHz Dual-core Intel Core i5
Memory 8GB 1600MHz DDR3
macOS Catalina 10.15.6

latex bench.tex  0.64s user 0.10s system 98% cpu 0.752 total
pdflatex bench.tex  1.08s user 0.15s system 99% cpu 1.237 total
xelatex bench.tex  1.60s user 0.34s system 110% cpu 1.769 total
lualatex bench.tex  3.00s user 0.41s system 99% cpu 3.431 total
```

As can be seen from the [results](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/franz/latex-bench) page, the best performing latex numbers are from Intel's chip with specs:

```
Core i7-6700K, 4200MHz (Turbo), 8MB L3, Debian Jessie (64-bit)  0.200
```

At `0.20s` it outperforms Apple M1 chip's `0.35s` in this very short benchmark test. And that is Intel's discontinued 6th generation chip from Q'3 2015 as per their [website](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88195/intel-core-i7-6700k-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-20-ghz.html). As of writing this post, Intel has recently released their 11th generation chips. If there is a consistent 10-20% improvement in performance of Intel chips per generation, one would guess that the latest 11th generation Intel chip should finish this test in around `0.10s` (though one cannot really say without testing, and as can be seen in updates below, it seems unlikely).

> UPDATE-1: We don't know if this `0.20s` number is from a desktop with more big heat sink or from laptop. Laptop's with Intel CPUs are traditionally clocked with a lower base frequency, and can enter into "turbo" mode for much shorter periods of time. This is why the performance of Intel chip in top-of-the-line 16 inch MacBook Pro from 2019 reported in comment to this answer (look below) looks worse than a Q'3 2015 Intel chip. Also, from another article [here](https://www.anandtech.com/show/15385/intels-confusing-messaging-is-comet-lake-better-than-ice-lake), it doesn't look like Intel is able to pull a 10-20% better performance over the board (per "generation"), and to the contrary its newer generation CPU design seems to have done a tradeoff to improve some applications performance at the expense of others.

> UPDATE-2: Here's [a video](https://youtu.be/zlmkoOwBC4U) that compares M1 chip with the latest Intel 11th generation chips in laptop chassis, and Intel's chip has lower performance in laptop chassis despite being its  latest generation. With bigger heat sink, room, and fan in a desktop chassis it might sustain more of its turbo mode (even more with nitrogen cooling like in this [video](https://youtu.be/QmSBaizEqkk)).

The latex benchmark (used in this answer) needs to be taken with a grain of salt though for a bunch of reasons: 1) we only have one test file, 2) test is too short considering speeds of modern processors (and length of time it takes for them to  throttle down).

**Intel processors in laptop chassis throttle down quite a lot within minutes** as per videos I have seen comparing Cinebench repeat-loop performance tests; while Apple M1 gives never-ending consistent performance as it doesn't generate heat at a fast rate as Intel CPUs. Unless one does a really long test, one cannot know for sure.

While working, latex is not the only application I keep open & work on. So I wouldn't just look at latex command line time performance of some small test file as it doesn't tell the real story if I am looking for a primary work computer.

**Part-2: "User experience"**

First "huge" noticeable difference, and improvement in quality of life that I see from switching to M1 Mac is it is dead silent, dead cold, with snappy-fast user interface.

I have installed fresh copy of MacTeX/TeX Live on 2014 MacBook Pro every year since I have had that computer. It has been a consistently horrible experience that I preferred avoiding each time as the loud fans would be blowing hot air by the end of the process (downloading and installing 5/6GB of data, and doing package updates worth another GB). On the contrary, M1 Mac was dead silent, and the little air it blew (which wasn’t audible even close to the device) felt colder than my room temperature (other users on YouTube have reported a similar experience).

**Power consumption** As per [this article](https://www.anandtech.com/show/16252/mac-mini-apple-m1-tested) on Anandtech (the most reputed source in CPU benchmarking industry), this device sips an idle power of just 4.2 Watts with peak 14.7 Watt under heavy Single thread workloads (latex runs single threaded). From the YouTube videos I have seen, Intels CPUs in laptop chassis easily operate at 35 (or above) watts for benchmarks where M1 remained well under 15W and gave comparable or better performance. This means more cost saving on electricity bills. Having such a low idle power (with wifi, and bluetooth on) means that it opens up other use cases like keeping it always on, and running CI/CD latex builds (among other things) on this device. The price point of $699 for base model of M1 Mac (8GB unified memory, and 256GB SSD) is also lucrative. Similar mini desktop "NUC" devices from Intel are more expensive.

Everything on software side (so far) in my testing looks fine, including programs that run under Rosetta 2. I did have initial bluetooth connectivity issue as also reported by some reviewers, though that doesn't really affect me as I use a Logitech Keyboard/Mouse setup that comes with its own tiny USB wireless dongle.

The Magic Trackpad is another user-interface/user-experience device that simply has no rival in industry, their keyboard is good too.

To wrap up, it depends on what you want to do with your next device. If you want to just get raw latex performance, then overclocking an Intel CPU with nitrogen cooling would give the best performance results. If you want a machine with good tradeoffs and comparable performance, M1 seems a better option.

Comment: For comparison's sake, on my 2019 MBP 16", I get `latex bench  0.43s user 0.03s system 99% cpu 0.456 total` with 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7

Comment: @DonHosek Thanks Don! Thats a good reference to have. I have referred readers to your comment in my UPDATE quotes above. It might be worthwhile to mention results for all four engines. If you would like to do that, feel free to edit the post with similar format that I use: machine specs followed by results of all four engines.

Comment: Darwin 19.6.0, macOS 10.15.7, 2 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5, MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020), TeX Live 2020: `latex real 0m0.662s`; `xelatex real 0m1.299s`; `lualatex real 0m2.286s`

Comment: `pdflatex bench  0.76s user 0.05s system 92% cpu 0.878 total`
`xelatex bench  1.12s user 0.16s system 81% cpu 1.566 total`
`lualatex bench  2.35s user 0.17s system 92% cpu 2.722 total`

Comment: It's interesting that xelatex and lualatex take so much longer than pdflatex.

Comment: So, can texshop, mactex run on macbook air 2020 with M1?

Comment: @JieFan Yes, check this: https://www.tug.org/mactex/aboutarm.html

Answer (score 5):

I tested [bench.tex](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/anton/latex-bench/) from reportamans answer on my MacBook Pro  (13-inch, M1, 2020, 16 GB), after MacTeX got updated to Apple Silicon on April 1st 2021.
I was a bit disappointed first.

Execution of

```
% latex bench
% bibtex bench
% latex bench
% time latex bench >> /dev/null
```

got me

```
0,36s user 0,04s system 80% cpu 0,503 total
```

Thats only a bit better than a 2012 i7 iMac, according to http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/franz/latex-bench

But I realized that there was only 80% CPU usage and there's no way of guaranteeing, that the task will be send to one of the four performance cores instead of the 4 efficiency cores.

My general subjective impression is: large projects like my Disseration compile in less than half the time, as on my previous i7 (2015 MacBook Pro). Without the fan spinning up. Quite frankly it's the best machine I've ever had.

%%%% EDIT %%%%

Comparing with the execution through rosetta 2 via command line environment:

```
env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 time latex bench >> /dev/null
```

That yielded a runtime of 0,57 seconds.

```
    0.57 real         0.42 user         0.04 sys
```

Hence, native latex without rosetta runs 13% faster on the M1 in that scenario.

Comment: Maybe because when you were running it, there already were other high priority processes. If you really want to get highest performance, you will have to ``nice``it at launch time. On macOS that requires superuser permissions. The safe way to do that is described in this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72959/456507

Comment: Thanks for the tipp on nice. Never tried it on MacOS before. However, nicing does  not change the CPU usage and only slightly decreases runtime:
```% sudo nice -n -20 su  <user> -c "time latex bench"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
[...]
Output written on bench.dvi (35 pages, 220792 bytes).
Transcript written on bench.log.
latex bench  0,35s user 0,04s system 80% cpu 0,484 total```

Answer (score 2):

I've purchased a new M1 Macbook Air and Mac Mini and can confirm that build times for the same files as compared to our 2.3 Ghz 8-core i9 Macs are about twice as fast on the M1 Macbook's.

Comment: Thanks, can you please add more exact spec of your i9 Mac machine like in the format that I use, also helpful would be the values for all four engines.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#news, **binaries** for nativ support on ARM and Intel are provided since **MacTeX 2021** (see the link for more details). This is compatible with https://isapplesiliconready.com/ and https://doesitarm.com/app/mactex.